# Why isn't JavaScript working as expected in Rails 6?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

Any JavaScript isn't working in my rails app. I have included

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

in `application.html.erb`, and this

```
console.log("something")
```

in `application.js` file, but my console is empty. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I (webpacker 6), don't know why. I had to use `javascript_packs_with_chunks_tag` instead of `javascipt_pack_tag`